# Adding two jwt validators to api endpoint through krakenD

Tags: authentication, proxy, jwt, api-gateway, krakend

I have two authentication mechanisms that I need to enable through proxy using krakenD. Each authentication has their own jwk-url to validate the keys of the token. I am using krakenD community edition 1.3 and following the krakenD documentation for jwt validation here https://www.krakend.io/docs/v1.3/authorization/jwt-validation/. Is there a way to add two jwt validators to the same endpoint?

```
{
      "endpoint": "/paas/hydra/test/ab/projects/{project}",
      "method": "GET",
      "output_encoding": "no-op",
      "headers_to_pass": ["Authorization"],
      "extra_config": {
        "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-jose/validator": {
          "alg": "RS256",
          "jwk-url": "{{ .jwk.host }}/oauth2/v1/keys",
          "cache": true,
          "cache_duration": 1800,
          "disable_jwk_security": true
        },
        "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-jose/validator": {
          "alg": "RS256",
          "jwk-url": "https://authbluetokens.aexp.com/v2/app2app/tokens/keys",
          "cache": true,
          "cache_duration": 1800,
          "disable_jwk_security": true
        }
      },
      "backend": [
        {
          "method": "GET",
          "encoding": "no-op",
          "host": ["http://localhost:8080"],
          "url_pattern": "/v6/workspaces/{project}",
          "extra_config": {
            "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend/transport/http/client/executor": {
              "name": "bomoktacustom",
              "audienceid": "0oasx1emolGCrwnht0x7,0oasx1nyh6ytqb96z0x7,0oaohi3lo9nr9lMXu0x7,0oarc7drtoyMIbAic0x7,0oaqnh8rpuaCUFhD70x7,0oaqctxj5rYvoUVuy0x7,0oappvfm4hre783rH0x7,0oawdujgrqi4DPyBz0x7,*.aexp.com"
            },
            "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-ratelimit/juju/proxy": {
              "maxRate": 6,
              "capacity": 6
            },
            "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-martian": {
              "header.Modifier": {
                "scope": ["request", "response"],
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/json"
              }
            }
          }

        }
      ]
    },
```

As shown in the code, I have tried adding two `krakend-jose/validator`  to the same endpoint. The current behavior of this implementation is krakenD ignores the first validator and only utilizes the second one. When using a token that requires the first validator krakenD returns `Error #01: no Keys has been found`. But using a token with the second validator works. The behavior I need is krakenD allowing to validate both type of tokens. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for works only in the enterprise edition: https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/authentication/multiple-identity-providers/ (it was also available on EE v1.3)

The community version expects 1 identity provider per endpoint only. Duplicating the keys or any other approach is not going to have the desired outcome.